# Rear derailleur shifts all gears at once

Tags: shifter, derailleur-rear, cable, campagnolo, skipping

I've got Campagnolo Veloce gear system and I recently changed my worn-out rear cassette to a new one. Since then I've experienced issues when shifting to higher gears. When I shift, the cable moves all the way to its extreme position, or at least skips 3 cogs. Shifting to lower gears works just fine. This issue is likely not related to the pulley/cassette because I can feel the shifter releasing way too much even if the cable is not connected to rear derailleur.

I have done the indexing and H, L and B screw tuning. Do you have any suggestions how to fix this?

EDIT: The chains were also changed at the same time with the cassette.

Comment: I don't have an answer, but if your cassette was worn out, there is a good chance your chain may be stretched/worn-out too. Using a stretched chain on a brand new cassette can cause shifting problems.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! However, I changed the chains at the same time with the worn-out cassette but I forgot to mention about that.

Comment: It sounds to me like your shifter is sticking, or perhaps your cable is sticking.  Cables do wear out, and they also (except for some newer styles) need occasional lubrication.  And shifters stick, especially in cool weather.

Comment: No, it was not the cable. I changed it to new one (and lubricated it) and the problem persists as it was before. Maybe I need to change the whole shifter thing.

Comment: You're in, say, your second biggest gear and you press down one click with your right thumb and it's shifting down three cogs instead of one?

Comment: Yes, if I try to press really fast. If I press the button properly (it has only one click anyway) it goes all the way to the heaviest gear, from 1 to 10! My hunch currentyl is that there's broken spring inside the right shifter.

Comment: Maybe the new chain is the wrong width?

Comment: The switching problem persists even when the rear derailleur is detached. When the shifter is at lowest position, I shift one click and the cable is released all the way to opposite extreme position. Thus, I don't think it's the chain here.

Comment: Yeah, sounds like a problem with the shifter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is worn out (or broken) index springs aka G-springs. These are part of the shifter mechanism. Worn out G-springs will enable rear derailleur spring to pull the cable over the indexes.

One way to test is putting the rear derailleur on bigger sprocket and pull the cable. If it drops indexes (goes to smaller sprocket) then the problem is caused by G-springs.

G-springs are replaceable in older (pre 2007) Campagnolo shifters. Only tools needed are hex keys.

Comment: This explains it! So, later Campagnolo shifters do not have replaceable G-springs?

Comment: New Campagnolo shifters have all new inner parts. Replaceable parts are bigger combinations rather than single springs or index rings.

Answer (score 0):

How old is your Veloce system?

This may (as previously commented) be a spring issue in a pre-2007 system.

After that, it's a whole-shifter-body issue, except for Veloce UltraShift, available only in 2009 - these shifter units are serviceable, although you do need the parst which are now almost impossible to find (we have them here at the main UK Campagnolo Service Centre).

Comment: I do not remember which issue it is. It was bought in the summer 2007. I opened the shifter and tried to figure out what was going on, but the inner parts were hard to access. Later, also my rear derailleur broke so I upgraded to new Athena parts. No issues anymore.